# How to use where and or_where in ignited datatables with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

It's not working at `->or_where('text like',"%dog%")`. I'm using it to make a json format to view in datatable
Please help me!

```
       $this->datatables->select('id,name,text,profile_image_url') //Ignited datatables
        ->unset_column('id')
        ->unset_column('profile_image_url')
        ->unset_column('name')
        ->unset_column('text')
        ->add_column('profile_image_url', '<img src="$1"/>', 'profile_image_url')
        ->add_column('name','$1','name')
        ->add_column('text','$1','text')
        ->where('text like',"%cat%")
        ->or_where('text like',"%dog%")
        ->from('posts');

       echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not working cause you have invalide syntax, using ->where means your are comparing if the column is equal to your second parameter, to use like function your syntax should be

```
$this->db->like('text', 'cat');
$this->db->like('text2', 'dog');
```

But if you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both' (which is the default).

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match'  

$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%' 

$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%' which is default
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I understood your mean. But I just used ignited datatables's code to create a jsons array to support view on datatable. It don't use normal code like "$this->db->like('text', 'cat');" in codeigniter's database code.

I have tried it and it have returned  a null array.

```
    $this->datatables->select('id,name,text,profile_image_url')
        ->unset_column('id')
        ->unset_column('profile_image_url')
        ->unset_column('name')
        ->unset_column('text')
        ->add_column('profile_image_url', '<img src="$1"/>', 'profile_image_url')
        ->add_column('name','$1','name')
        ->add_column('text','$1','text')
        // ->like("text","%dog%");
        // ->like("text","cat");
        ->from('posts');
        $this->db->like("text","dog");
        $this->db->like("text","cat");

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
```